# How to validate email input on java

Tags: java

how to validate emailfield input with

1. Not starts with ‘@’ or ‘.’
2. Not contains more than 1 ‘@’ or ‘.’

i have already code the emailfield to have more than 14 character, end with ‘.com’, and make ‘@’ next to ‘.’

```
     String regemail = emailfield.getText();

     if ( !regemail.contains("@") ) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Email must contain '@' once");
     emailfield.requestFocus();
     return false;
     } else

     if ( !regemail.contains(".com") ) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Email must contain '.com' 
     once");
     emailfield.requestFocus();
     return false;  
     } else

     if ( regemail.indexOf("@")
     > regemail.lastIndexOf(".com") ) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Email Format");
     emailfield.requestFocus();
     return false;
     } else

     if(regemail.length() < 13) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Email length must more 
           than 14 characters");
     emailfield.requestFocus();
     return false;
     }
```

Comment: **Many** email addresses contain more than one dot, and **many** don't end in `.com`. And many are shorter than 14 characters.

Comment: And note the real message of the accepted answer to the dup question.  Validating email addresses is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use a regex:

```
  private final Pattern EMAIL_ADDRESSS_REGEX_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

private boolean isValidEmail(String email)
{
    return EMAIL_ADDRESSS_REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(email).find();

}
```